# Access a custom model from the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using asp.net MVC 4 and razor syntax. I have a custom model, imagine this:

```
namespace MyProject.SampleModel
{
    public class MyCustomModel
    {
        public bool MyBoolean1 { get; set; }
        public bool MyBoolean2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

so from the view, in the header, I do:

```
@model MyProject.SampleModel.MyCustomModel

(...)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MyBoolean1 ) <---- ERROR HERE: MyBoolean1 is not recognized
(...)
```

But in line CheckBoxFor, in the lambda, my MyBoolean1 is not recognized. Why?

**First attempt:**

It seems like replacing

```
@model MyProject.SampleModel.MyCustomModel
```

with:

```
@using MyProject.SampleModel
```

there are no compilation errors but in runtime an error is raised:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1963: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation
```

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
@using MyProject.SampleModel
```

with

```
@model MyProject.SampleModel.MyCustomModel
```

As the error states, lambda expressions do not support dynamic models. By defining the model you are strongly typing it.

Using your faulty statement, you are referencing just a namespace, which will per se work, if you elimenate your lambda expressions from the code, but you won't have a strongly typed view any longer.

Kind regards

**//EDIT:**

We found out, that the core of the question is: how to use 2(3, 4, 5 ... n) models in one view.

Lets assume you have model 1:

```
public class MyCustomModel
{
    public bool MyBoolean1 { get; set; }
    public bool MyBoolean2 { get; set; }
}
```

And model 2:

```
public class SecondModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

You need to create a third class which combines these two models.

```
public class ExampleViewModel
{
    public MyCustomModel BoolValues { get; set; }
    public SecondModel Names { get; set; }
}
```

Now you just return an ExampleViewModel to your view in your controller action and use

```
@model MyProject.SampleModel.ExampleViewModel
```

and access your properties in this way:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.BoolValues)
{
    <div>@item.Myboolean1</div>
}

@foreach (var item in Model.Names)
{
    <div>@item.FistName</div>
}
```

Comment: On runtime below error is raised by doing what you have said:Compiler Error Message: CS0118: 'MyProject.SampleModel' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'

Comment: I didn't realise you were referencing a namespace instead of a class and just saw the `using` vs. `model` error. I edited my answer for better understanding.

Comment: If I delete the line the namespace and the import to the view as @model MyCustomModel then works. The problem here is that imagine I have another custom model and I want to import as well: the problem is that you cannot import more than one model...and now I have this problem.

Comment: Yes you can. What you need is a `ViewModel` Just google it or use one of the questions here on SO as a reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548376/asp-net-mvc-how-exactly-to-use-view-models. I will edit my answer to give a quick heads up for you

Comment: I have tried yet as well but without success. Lambdas in lines @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MyBoolean1) are not working. Also I have another problem, in my script block I have something like @Model.SecondModel for example and it is not working.

Comment: Ok, for lambdas @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.BoolValues.MyBoolean1) works but now I have problems in the script block @Model.SecondModel

Comment: Do NOT use 2 models seperatly in one view. Build the ViewModel like I explained and use the ViewModel.

Comment: And If I need to access to a custom model, for example, SecondModel.FirstName in the script zone, how to do this?

Comment: I have explained the basics in my answer, even on how to access FirstName. Only in this case it is called `Names.FirstName` because I have instantiated it this way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37759/discussion-between-serv-and-user1624552)